# iPhone UITableView. How do turn on the single letter alphabetical list like the Music App?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

In the iPhone music app, selecting Artist, Songs, or Albums presents a tableView with a verticl list of single letters at the righthand side of the UI that enables rapid scrolling. How do I enable this functionality in my app?

Cheers,
Doug

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Supply your own index characters:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"e", @"i", @"m", @"p", nil];
}
```

and then:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString
    *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
        return <yourSectionIndexForTheSectionForSectionIndexTitle >;
}
```

You will need sections.

Comment: Is there a way to have indexes without having sections (for a flat list)?

Comment: @ThEuSeFuL You can have sections without showing section headers. This would look like a flat list to the end user.

Comment: what is"yourSectionIndexForTheSectionForSectionIndexTitle" meant by?

Comment: @ravoorinandan he essentially means return the index of the title variable in your titles array. So if the title is @"a", it should return 0. If the title is @"i", it should return 2, and so forth. You can do this by making the array available to both methods shown here and then calling [array indexOfObject: title] in the second method. Though I would say that the answer below this (related to UILocalizedIndexedCollation) is probably better.

Comment: Just in case, anyone did the same mistake as mine, select the tableView in the storyboard and change the text colour to your desired colour. In my case, the text colour was automatically selected as clear colour and therefore index was not listing. I wasted quite a lot of time figuring out what is the issue.

Answer (score 35):

Something else you have to consider is localizing the sections for each language.  After digging around a bit, I found `UILocalizedIndexedCollation` to be quite useful:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionTitles] objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionIndexTitles];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex:index];
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilocalizedindexedcollation

Answer (score 33):

I came up with an alternative approach to handling a single letter alphabet list without using sections. It's similar to Zaph's answer but instead of getting any value from returning a new index (since we'll always have 1 section), we calculate the index for the location of the first item in the array that begins with a certain character, then scroll to it.

The downside is this requires searching the array every time (is this absolutely terrible?), however I didn't notice any lag or slow behavior in the iOS simulator or on my iPhone 4S.

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  return[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z", nil];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {

  NSInteger newRow = [self indexForFirstChar:title inArray:self.yourStringArray];
  NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newRow inSection:0];
  [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];

  return index;
}

// Return the index for the location of the first item in an array that begins with a certain character
- (NSInteger)indexForFirstChar:(NSString *)character inArray:(NSArray *)array
{
  NSUInteger count = 0;
  for (NSString *str in array) {
    if ([str hasPrefix:character]) {
      return count;
    }
    count++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

adding property to store last selected index like

```
 @property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger previousSearchIndex;
```

and storing this property every time like:

```
- (NSInteger)indexForFirstChar:(NSString *)character inArray:(NSArray *)array
{
    NSUInteger count = 0;
    for (NSString *str in array) {
        if ([str hasPrefix:character]) {
            self.previousSearchIndex = count;
            return count;
        }
        count++;
    }
    return self.previousSearchIndex;
}
```

and updating `scrollToRow` code like:

```
 [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Do this method even better and with nice animation.

Comment: upvoted just since it means I didn't have to type in the alphabet array!

Comment: heh. it's also not a bad solution either ...apple accepted me for cocoa camp using this in my code sample. whether that means they officially endorse it or not... I do not know ;).

Comment: @PaulCezanne Actually, to make it cleaner I suggest you loop through your array of strings and grab the upperCase first letters of all strings so that your list is dynamic in that you won't have any Q's if you don't have any items that begin with the letter Q. Let me know if you'd like me to update my code to show this.

Comment: Thanks. I actually did that in another app I was working on. It looked pretty weird in practice. The A-Z array on the side is pretty explanatory. When you have only a few letter, which you will have if you only have a small number of songs or if you've filtered a lot, the purpose of the letters along the side looks odd.

Comment: @PaulCezanne Good point, I could see that being odd. Probably looks better to just have them all there and do something like move to the next closest letter if there are none that begin with the currently selected letter.

Comment: Yes, and that actually just works without any extra coding. Looks fine also.

Comment: I have a problem when I adopt you code   that is not actually jumping to the right letter , its just scrolling 26 positions down ..

Comment: @Mingebag Try debugging it by checking what indexForFirstChar's return value is each time it's called. It should be between 0 and 25 each time. If it's > 25 then perhaps you have non-alphabetical characters or something else causing it to return too high a value.

Comment: @PaulCezanne the code does not work as is for me in the case of clicking on an index for which there are no strings with that letter. Posting modified version below.

Comment: @KyleClegg, two questions: 1. With your example, if "J" is selected but no ArrayStrings begin with "J", how can we make tableView scroll to "I" or "H" if needed. 2. How to make the 'quickScroll' to show all letters? (right now it shows "A ◉ D ◉ G ◉ I ... etc."

Answer (score 21):

A bunch of people asked if it was possible to do this without sections. I wanted the same thing and I found a solution which might be a little shady and doesn't return a value to sectionForSectionIndexTitle but if you are in a corner and don't want to have to make a section for every letter of the alphabet this is a sure fix. Sorry to any code Nazis in advance. :P

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (thisTableDataIsShowing)
    {
        NSMutableArray *charactersForSort = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (NSDictionary *item in d_itemsInTable)
        {
            if (![charactersForSort containsObject:[[item valueForKey:@"character_field_to_sort_by"] substringToIndex:1]])
            {
                [charactersForSort addObject:[[item valueForKey:@"character_field_to_sort_by"] substringToIndex:1]];
            }
        }
        return charactersForSort;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    BOOL found = NO;
    NSInteger b = 0;
    for (NSDictionary *item in d_itemsInTable)
    {
        if ([[[item valueForKey:@"character_field_to_sort_by"] substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:title])
            if (!found)
            {
                [d_yourTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:b inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
                found = YES;
            }
        b++;
    }
}
```

It works great if you are getting a large amount of data and sectioning it would take a bunch of work. :) Tried to use generic variables so you knew what I was doing. d_itemsInTable is an NSArray of NSDictionaries that I'm listing out to the UITableView.

Comment: Fun fax: If you return -1, it will ignore compiler warnings, and not try to scroll to that section from the sectionForSectionIndexTitle method

Comment: Really awesome sample thanks allot maybe adding a brake after fund= YES; would also not be that bad ^^

Answer (score 3):

Here is a modified version of Kyle's function that handles the case of clicking an index for which you do not have a string:

```
- (NSInteger)indexForFirstChar:(NSString *)character inArray:(NSArray *)array
{
    char testChar = [character characterAtIndex:0];
    __block int retIdx = 0;
    __block int lastIdx = 0;

    [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        char firstChar = [obj characterAtIndex:0];

        if (testChar == firstChar) {
            retIdx = idx;
            *stop = YES;
        }

        //if we overshot the target, just use whatever previous one was
        if (testChar < firstChar) {
            retIdx = lastIdx;
            *stop = YES;
        }

        lastIdx = idx;
    }];
    return retIdx;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a `NSFetchedResultsController`, you can just do:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [frc sectionIndexTitles];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return [frc sectionForSectionIndexTitle:title atIndex:index];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Implement the delegate methods `-sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:` and `-tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:`

See the [`UITableViewDataSource`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006941-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1) documentation for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution in Swift, assuming you have your title headers in an array.  If the title couldn't be found, it will return the previous index in the array.

```swift
func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    return "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".characters.flatMap{String($0)}
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, atIndex index: Int) -> Int {
    return self.headerTitles.filter{$0 <= title}.count - 1
}
```

Comment: I think it is preferable to change the second return line to `return self.headerTitles.count - self.headerTitles.filter{$0 > title}.count` to return the index of the first rather than the last matching section for the given index title.

Comment: Depends on what the client expects, really.  Chances are, whichever functionality you choose will be the opposite of what they want.  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MonoTouch, override the SectionIndexTitles(UITableView) method in the UITableViewDataSource class.  Just return an array of strings and the subclass takes care of the rest.

```
class TableViewDataSource : UITableViewDataSource
{
  public override string[] SectionIndexTitles(UITableView tableView) 
  { 
    return new string[] { /*your string values */};
  }
}
```

*just a hint for those of us using C# and Mono (.NET) to write iPhone apps. :)