# Custom Scrollbar for UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, itunes

the iTunes song list display is a TableView that has a dotted scrollbar on the right which allows me to jump to a relative position of the list (i.e. if I click the bar at 2/3 down I am scrolled to the 66% position of the list.

I want to do the same in my UITableView, but am not sure whether this is standard functionality that I can use (which class?) or whether this is a custom build ...

If the latter, has someone got some samplecode that I could use as a template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% what you're talking about when you say dotted scrollbar, I think you're referring to the letters down the side, if so, take a look here:

[iPhone UITableView. How do turn on the single letter alphabetical list like the Music App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655119/iphone-uitableview-how-do-turn-on-the-single-letter-alphabetical-list-like-the-m)

Comment: for lists with section headers iTunes shows the alphabetical list. Where no section headers exist (like no album titles) it shows the dottet bar I was talking about (i.e. I have a playlist with radiostations that do not have album titles).

Thanks for the link, that's what I was after. Will see whether that also reveals how to get the dotten bar ....