# how to split NSArray into alphabetical sections for use with index tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a NSArray that I have parsed and sorted alphabetically from some xml I am getting from my database. I am now wondering how to split this array up for use with a index on a tableview for quicker searching.

Where my table gets a bit different is that it dosn't alway use the whole alphabet, and unlike most examples I have found the dataset I use varies alot from day to day..

so I am trying to figure out how to split a sorted array into alphabetical sections that are not always the same.

As cocofu pointed out, Yes I have got my sectionIndexTitlesForTableView already implemented, I am now trying to split my nsarray into sections so that scrolling works with sectionIndexTitlesForTableView.

Comment: See if this SO Q&A helps: [ALphabetic list][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655119/iphone-uitableview-how-do-turn-on-the-single-letter-alphabetical-list-like-the-m/1655218#1655218

Comment: Sorry I should say that I have my sectionIndexTitlesForTableView already set. The part I am now trying to figure out is how to put my NSarray into sections so that scrolling works with the sectionIndexTitlesForTableView I have declared. thank you for the suggestion however.

Answer (score 6):

I would create an NSSet with the first letters you use in your array and then create a sorted array from that. Assuming all of the first letters are of the correct case, it would look something like:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
   NSMutableSet *mySet = [[[NSMutableSet alloc] init] autorelease];
   for ( NSString *s in myArray )
   {
     if ( s.length > 0 )
       [mySet addObject:[s substringToIndex:1]];
   }

   NSArray *indexArray = [[mySet allObjects] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
   return indexArray;
}
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution compared to what I have currently for setting my sectionIndexTitlesForTableView, I was looking at a similar example I found not long ago that was talking about this.. but didnt have any code.. thanks for that, will have a play around with it now.

Comment: what code is going to be in the `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare` method?

Comment: That method is built into NSString. No additional code needed.

Comment: Brilliant, +1. Just a small enhancement: `[mySet addObject:[s substringWithRange:[s rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:(NSRange){0, 1}]]];` With that you're safe against surrogate pairs and other composed code fragments.

Answer (score 3):

You could use an NSPredicate to derive the data like so:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH 'a'"];
NSArray *aElements = [myArray filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

I would love to hear of a more efficient way instead of looping or having 26 NSPredicate Statements being run for every letter of the Alphabet or doing a loop with the characters and returning the elements.

You could store each filtered array in an NSDictionary with all the letters of the alphabet as the keys and then retrieve it later and check if it's empty (which means it has no elements for that letter). I believe BEGINSWITH is Case-Sensitive

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I am still searching the internet for good examples also as this whole process of indexing tableviews seems very drawn out and ambiguous.. I will let you know of any solutions I find, that is unless something usefull pops up here.

Comment: Instead of doing the sorting at the table view layer, maybe you should be doing it at the model layer when you retrieve the data set so you only need to do it once. When you create the NSArray it's easier to check and then preprocess the dictionary of arrays with alphabetical keys rather than search later using the NSPredicate.

Comment: I know what mvc is and how it works.. but I am struggling to remember how it works in ios, is the controller (delegate) and model (class object) with the view being the nibs?? I have been trying to find something to refresh my memory but am at a loss :P Time to go find a book to read again.

Comment: anything new on efficient tableview indexes here?

Answer (score -1):

"arr" here contains all the results which fetched from database or after parsing xml or whatever.

Just sort array in ascending order (arrSortedResults in my code).

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];   
        NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"c",@"a1",@"b1",@"c1",@"a2",@"a3",@"a4",@"b", nil];

                tableGroupView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];//simply initialization of tableview
                tableGroupView.delegate=self;
                tableGroupView.dataSource=self;
                [self.view addSubview:tableGroupView];

                NSArray *arrSortedResults= [arr sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

        ArrayForArrays=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];//initialize a array to hold arrays for section of table view

                BOOL checkValueAtIndex=NO;  //flag to check
                SectionHeadsKeys=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:nil];//initialize a array to hold keys like A,B,C ...

                for(int index=0;index<[arrSortedResults count];index++)
                {
                    NSMutableString *strchar=[arrSortedResults objectAtIndex:index];
                    NSString *sr=[strchar substringToIndex:1];
                    NSLog(@"%@",sr);//sr containing here the first character of each string
                 if(![SectionHeadsKeys containsObject:[sr uppercaseString]])//here I'm checking whether the character already in the selection header keys or not
                        {
                            [SectionHeadsKeys addObject:[sr uppercaseString]];
                            TempArrForGrouping=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:nil];
                            checkValueAtIndex=NO;
                        }
                    if([SectionHeadsKeys containsObject:[sr uppercaseString]])
                    {
                        [TempArrForGrouping addObject:[arrSortedResults objectAtIndex:index]];
                        if(checkValueAtIndex==NO)
                        {
                            [ArrayForArrays addObject:TempArrForGrouping];
                            checkValueAtIndex=YES;
                        }
                    }
                }

      }  
        //after this ArrayForArrays will contain all the arrays which will become groups under the header headerkeys

            - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
                return [ArrayForArrays count];
            }

            - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
            {
                return [SectionHeadsKeys objectAtIndex:section];
            }

            - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
            {
                NSArray *arr=  [ArrayForArrays objectAtIndex:section];

                return [arr count];


            }

            - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
                     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
                static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
                UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView
                                          dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
                if(cell == nil) {
                    cell =[[UITableViewCell alloc]
                           initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                           reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
                }
                int section=[indexPath section];
                NSArray *arr=[ArrayForArrays objectAtIndex:section];
                cell.textLabel.text=[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                return cell;
            }

            now output will be as bellow:

            ![enter image description here][1]



      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcPr6.png
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, care to add some explanation to your code?