# What is the Vertical Alphabet in the iOS Phonebook Called?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, addressbook

Is the little vertical alphabet that that allows you to skip to a selected letter in the iOS contact manager a built in view of some type or is it some weird concoction of a custom view and delegate methods?

Thanks

Comment: Check the answer for this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655119/iphone-uitableview-how-do-turn-on-the-single-letter-alphabetical-list-like-the-m

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called an "indexed list" or "section index" in the documentation.

For a quick hint, look at the documentation for the `UITableViewDataSource` `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:` and `tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:` methods.

For more detailed information, check out the **Populating an Indexed List** section of the [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html)