# Sorting Array of Objects alphabetically based on a string attribute

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, sorting

I have a UITableView which is populated with an array of objects of type 'Product' which each have a 'name' attribute of type string.  When a cell is clicked, a modal view is shown with more information on that product.

What I would like to do is split the products up into sections depending on the first letter of their name attribute.  (Like iPhone contacts).

I have been struggling with this for a while now, and I can't seem to find anything online that solves my particular problem..

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several good examples here on SO.  Here is a good example:

[How to sort an NSMutableArray with custom objects in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it)

Comment: Thanks, that has shown me how to order the array alphabetically, but I'm still struggling to display the now organised array in a UITableView with alphabetical sections?

Comment: If you implement the UITableViewDataSource protocol, you can define the number of rows / sections and what cell shows up at each point.  You would use this sorted array to know what to present.  You can see the protocol here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: In addition, if you want the alphabetical index - see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655119/iphone-uitableview-how-do-turn-on-the-single-letter-alphabetical-list-like-the

Answer (score 3):

Use [NSSortDescriptor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSArray/sortedArrayHint) like this..

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor =
    [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name"
                                  ascending:YES
                                   selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSArray *sortedArray = [nameOfArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

Hope, this is what you're looking for. Any concern get back to me. :)