# What is that control called for Adress book scrolling

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, controls

Can you tell the name and source of the scroll item on the right in the screenshot?
In this sample it goes from "A" to "Z" and user can select the wanted name by tabbing on the right Character item.

[image]

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655119/iphone-uitableview-how-do-turn-on-the-single-letter-alphabetical-list-like-the)