# Sorting and Grouping UITableView in alphabetical order

Tags: ios, uitableview, sorting, nsarray

I have an array filled with items from MPMediaQuery and I am trying to figure out how to get each song sorted in alphabetical order in the tableview. How do I set up the table to show each section for each letter and fill each section with the songs. not sure what code would be relevant to post, but if you need, I will provide my code i have so far.

Comment: Did you look for sorting your array questions on SO? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655119/iphone-uitableview-how-do-turn-on-the-single-letter-alphabetical-list-like-the and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351182/how-to-sort-a-nsarray-alphabetically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to sort your array using a sort of `NSSortDescriptor`. Then you can create a different section for each letter. You also have to configure the tableviewcell properly.
Surely this will be helpful for you: https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html and https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html